# How could I create a custom behavior with datavalidation in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior, validation

I want to make a WPF control that will perform a custom behavior when validation fails (IE turn blue or change an arbitrary DP on the control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [add validation visual states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302.aspx) to the control or [apply a special ErrorTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx) these could take care of visual requirements such as turning blue.

Setting a property or calling a method could be done by subscribing to [the Error event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error.aspx) of the Validation class.